# AS3 Objects Issue with Switches

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having some issues with AS3 Object Arrays. I am trying to make an inventory system, which the user can navigate left and right (which is working). When the user presses ENTER the item should then equip.

I was going to use `switch` and `case` to equip the items, as there will only be around 8 items to the game. I get the result `[object purpleSword]` when using trace, but my `switch` isn't getting any results or firing anything. I need the `equipItem` function to find the `purpleSword` that's ben found in the `arrayItems`. Items are added to the `arrayItems` when picked up off the floor.

Does anyone have any tips for using Objects for an RPG inventory system? Many thanks in advance.

```
 public var arrayItems: Array = new Array();

    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
        if (currentScreen == "inventory") {
            if(inventoryCurrent >= 0) {
            var actualCurrentItem = inventoryCurrent - 1;

            equipItem(arrayItems[actualCurrentItem]);
            }
        }
     }

public function equipItem(itemNumber) {

        switch(itemNumber) {
            case "purpleSword":
                    trace("equip purple sword");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the items in your Array are not strings, then they cannot be found by your switch statement. In you switch statement, you're checking if the parameter itemNumber equals the string "purpleSword". If itemNumber isn't a string, or is a string with other content, then you will never reach this case.

Comment: AS3 has a type system, you should use it to help you understand your own errors, and help others understand your code (like us).

Answer (score 0):

**AS3 has a type system, you should use it to help you understand your own errors, and help others understand your code (like us).**

Given the fact that you say your output gives you `[object purpleSword]` I can assume you have a class `purpleSword`. My guess is that this is an exported symbol, not a .as class file, but it could be either.

But those are all guesses because you haven't provided any type information. For example:

- `arrayItems:Array` could contain *anything*, and you haven't told us what. You could use a `items:Vector.<Object>` to store objects, or `Vector.<Sprite>` to store symbols exported from your Flash library, or better yet create an `InventoryItem` class and use a `Vector.<InventoryItem>` to store them.
- `var actualCurrentItem` should be `var actualCurrentItem:int`
- `equipItem(itemNumber)` should be `equipItem(itemNumber:int):void`?

If you do this, you will realize (either through your own observation or the compiler telling you) that your `equipItem()` function is wrong: it expects an `itemNumber` but it will receive an object.

If my prior assumptions were correct, you could do this:

```
public var items:Vector.<Object> = new <Object>[];

if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
    if (currentScreen == "inventory") {
        if(inventoryCurrent >= 0) {
            var actualCurrentItem:int = inventoryCurrent - 1;
            equipItem(items[actualCurrentItem]);
        }
    }
 }

public function equipItem(item:Object):void {
    switch(item.constructor) {
        case purpleSword:
            trace("equip purple sword");
            break;
    }
}
```

This works because [`Object/constructor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#constructor) is a reference to the class of any object, ie `purpleSword` class, etc. However, you *really* should use something more concrete than `Object`, which could be *any* kind of object and tells you nothing about what kind of properties it might have.